# Drupal 8 + Twig background-color -field select

Tags: theming, 8

How I do with twig this:

I got list -field where I got differents color:

black|Black

grey|Grey

---

black = background-color: #000;

grey = background-color: #eee;

---

When I select Black it will appear somewhere on the node or field.

```
<div class="black">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is provide a field template for that field that just prints the value and no markup:

**field--your-field-name.html.twig**:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then in the main template, wherever you want to output that field value, you would have:

```
<div class="{{ content.your_field_name|trim }}">Example</div>
```

The result should be just the field value, with no whitespace, so "black" or "grey".